# Character Walks backwards with no reason (Brackeys First Person Character Controller in Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use the First Person Character Controller Script from Brackeys. But sometimes, my character walks backwards with no button pressed. I've tried to change the values of the Character Controller and to change the values of the axis in the Project Settings, but  nothing really helped.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public Transform groundcheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpheight = 3f;

    Vector3 velocity;

    bool isGrounded;

    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundcheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpheight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }
}
```

I really dont know what the problem is, but maybe you can help me

Comment: What is the `velocity` vector good for if you anyway only want to use its `y` component? And then what does `Debug.Log(z);` give you?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Debug.Log(z) gives me the value -1 if I walk backwards

Comment: That sounds like something is triggering your `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` to be negative all the time...

Comment: I went through all of my Scripts, but I didnt found something, that could trigger my Vertical Axis. Is there a setting for the axis that could trigger this? Or maybe an component that wasnt adjusted the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the script. Something must be giving a vertical input outside the script.

If you're using a controller, your left joystick might have some drift issues. Adding some [deadzone](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-term-joystick-deadzone-mean) to your movement vector can prevent any involuntary movement from happening. For example, you can check if your input is inferior to a certain threshold and set it to zero if that's the case.
Here's a simple way to do it (in this example, the threshold is 0.125. If the joystick drift still gives an input, try an higher value.):

```
float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
if(x <= 0.125f)
   x = 0
if(y <= 0.125f)
   y = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late here but I had the same issue.
What caused it was having another controller plugged in besides mouse and keyboard, in my case a steering wheel. So make sure all extra controllers are unplugged